# Blender game engine module file location

Tags: blender-game-engine

Where can I find the "bge" module file ? It imports well from a python script but I want to know where from.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to get a peek in the BL_shader code

Comment: It's in the source code to Blender in "source\gameengine\Ketsji\BL_Shader.h" (and .cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there isn't an actual module file defining the `bge` module. Rather, the module is defined within Blender's actual engine code through Python's interop facilities.